# java alphabet loop reset to beginning

Tags: java

I want to create a loop where when you add a number, it gives you the equivalent character in that position in the alphabet. For example, a = 0, b = 1 etc..
I've already created that and it works, but the problem I have is that when it reaches 26, I would like it go back and continue the loop. For example, 25 is z, so 27 should be b.

Code:

```
char[] alphabet = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ".toLowerCase().toCharArray();
    if (i < 0) 
    {
        return null;
    }
    if(i > 25)
    {
        i = 0;
    }           
    return Character.toString(alphabet[i]); //converts character to String and returns the character
}
```

Comment: Use the % operator.

Comment: Where is the loop in your code?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the modulo operation on `i`.

```
char[] alphabet = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ".toLowerCase().toCharArray();
int i =30;
System.out.println(alphabet[i % alphabet.length]);
```

Comment: Shouldn't `i` here be 26?

Comment: I used `i=30` just as an example

Answer (score 1):

You don't need any arrays or loops at all. Just do this:

```
return (char)('a' + (i % 26));
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using a modulo operator for your indices. For example,

```
char[] alphabet = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ".toLowerCase().toCharArray();
if (i < 0) return;
i = i % 26;
return Character.toString(alphabet[i]);
```

Or

```
char[] alphabet = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ".toLowerCase().toCharArray();
if (i > 0)
    return Character.toString(alphabet[i % 26]);
else
    return;
```